# How to implement the header of a function such that the following code works?

Tags: c++

```
vector<int> v1{4, 2, 1, 6, 3, -4};
assert(fct<int>(v1) == 6);
vector<int> v2;
try {
        fct<int>(v2);
        assert(false);
}
catch (exception& exc) {
assert(true);
}
vector<double> v3{2, 10.5, 6.33, -100, 9, 1.212};
assert(fct<double>(v3) == 10.5);

vector<string> v4{"y", "q", "a", "m"};
assert(fct<string>(v4) == "y");
```

I know that the fct function should return the maximum of the vector but I can't wrap my head on how the header of the function should look like.

Comment: If this is not a homework, you should be using [`std::max_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element).

Comment: there is no `fct` that can make `assert(false)` pass and `assert` does not throw an exception that you can `catch`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you meant the function declaration (not "header"), so that's what it should look like:

```
template<typename T>
T fct(const std::vector<T>& v);
```

### PS:

1. You should not name that function "fct", but give it an appropriate name, like "max_element" or something (or use the function [std::max_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) provided by the standard lib)
2. Don't use `using namespace std;`
   see: [why is 'using namespace std;' considered bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)
3. <strike>If you're not bound to some older C++ standard (or compiler),</strike> you can omit the template parameter when calling your function: `assert(fct(v1) == 6);`

Comment: I don't think there was a C++ standard without template parameter deduction from function parameters. Are you refering to C++17s CTAD? `fct(v1)` isn't that.

Comment: Right, my bad. That was just class template argument deduction. Edited the Answer.